# Making a bar be at the absolute top of the window, all the way across

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my topnav is not the full width of my browser window (it goes almost the full length of the window, but not entirely, on both ends) and also there is a bit of space between it and the top of the browser window.

How do I make it so this is not the case? Here's my code:

```
#topnav
{
background-color: #A9A9A9;
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 25;
padding: 0;
}

#topnav ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
padding-top:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
}
#topnav li
{
display:inline;
}
#topnav a:link,a:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 12px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#A9A9A9;
text-align:center;
padding:6px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#topnav a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#808080;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="topnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.psp" id="index">Index</a></li>
<li<a href="inventory.psp">Inventory</a></li>
<li><a href="/checkup/checkup.psp">Check-Up</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

EDIT: Now the bar extends all across the browser, however there is still a gap up at the top.

Also, the gap is only present in Firefox - it does not show up in Chrome. My whole thing is messed up in IE.

Comment: Could you give the markup (html) as well? or even better, make a jsfiddle

Comment: try: body, html {margin:0;padding:0}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to the top problem try this:

```
#topnav {
background-color: #A9A9A9;
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 25;
padding: 0;

position:absolute;
top:0;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. However now my bar is a lot bigger and goes down to the other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

the #topnav -> margin & padding should be deleted since it is 0. The same counts for #topnav ul.

You could incorporate your navigation pane in a div which has a width of 100%. Let me know if that works for you.

**-- Edit: This should work in FF/Chrome/IE (just tested it)**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#topnav
{
background-color: #A9A9A9;
margin-bottom: 25;
width:100%;
top:0;
}

#topnav ul
{
list-style-type:none;
padding-top:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
}

#topnav li
{
display:inline;
}
#topnav a:link,a:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 12px;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#A9A9A9;
text-align:center;
padding:6px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
#topnav a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#808080;
}
</style>
<head/>
<body>
<div id="topnav">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.psp" id="index">Index</a></li>
<li<a href="inventory.psp">Inventory</a></li>
<li><a href="/checkup/checkup.psp">Check-Up</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This helps, making the bar the length of my browser window, however the gap at top is still present.